# Getting "Property 'openWith' on type 'oneDrive.item' is not a navigation property." when trying to access workbook api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-excel

My code was working just the day before. As I was trying to work on the progress yesterday.

The application was try to `createSession`,  and it was this error.

```
"code": "generalException",
"message": "Property 'openWith' on type 'oneDrive.item' is not a navigation property. Only navigation properties can be expanded.",
```

I went on to test on [graph-explorer](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer). It still shows the same error. Thus, I have confirm that it wasn't the error from the `createSession`.

Fyi. The others api is working, as I was able to call
`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Book1.xlsx` or `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/items/{id}` without any issue.

However, `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root:/Book1.xlsx:/workbook` was failing with the same error shown above.

Appreciate any help here, as I was debugging this for whole night already.

Comment: Can you provide an example `request-id` from the failure response?

Comment: Hi brad, thanks for the response.  If i remember correctly, the request-id keep on changing at the point of issue.

It seems that the error just magically disappear after a few weeks of leaving the API alone. =D
Wasn't sure what is the root cause though.

Anyway, I am able to proceed with my development for now.

Answer (score 1):

Just to close the loop on the comments of the original question - this ended up being an issue in Graph that was reverted.